# AngularJs 2 tab customClass conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I would like to set a customClass for the angular 2 bootstrap tab conditionally but only see that it is set with a static value.

Is it possible to set customClass conditionally?
http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs

html:
This works:

```
<tab index="1" customClass="myCustomClass">
```

This is what I want to do but it does not work:

```
<tab index="1" customClass="myCustomClass: myConditionIsTrue">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tab index="1" [customClass]="condition ? 'myCustomClass1' : 'myCustomClass2'">
```

this should work